# Object Object as title of element on hover

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an accordion element that I am using to display a number of FAQs on a page. The Code showing the accordion with content on the page is as follows:

```
         {
          Object.keys(FAQS).map((key, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={key}>
                <InputLabel display='block' ml='.5rem' mb='1rem' mt='2rem' active>{FAQS[index].section.toUpperCase()}</InputLabel>
                {
                  FAQS[index].questions.map((question, i) => {
                    return (
                      <Accordion key={i}
                        panelIndex={i}
                        p='1rem' j
                        icon={<PlusIcon w='1.2rem' h='1rem' color={colors.purple} />}
                        bg={i % 2 ? colors.white : colors.greyBg}
                        title={<Paragraph semiBold font={Theme.fonts.family.primary}>{question.question.toUpperCase()}</Paragraph>}
                        content={<Paragraph>{question.answer}</Paragraph>} />
                    );
                  })
                }
              </div>
            );
          })
        }
```

The problem is when I hover over the accordion title I see the title evaluated as `[Object Object]` instead of the proper title of the page even though the proper title is shown to a user who visits the page.

Below is an image of what I am seeing...
[image]

Please help

Structure of the question is:

```
[
  {
    section: 'General FAQs',
    questions: [
      {
        question: 'I',
        answer: '',
      },
      {
        question: '',
        answer: '',
      }
}]
```

And it generates the following element on the DOM:

```
<div class="Accordion__HeaderContainer-ue81ns-0 bipqoo" icon="[object Object]" title="[object Object]" content="[object Object]"><div class="Accordion__Header-ue81ns-1 cFDepz"><p class="Paragraph-gm6ys1-0 fjMUUV">I HAVEN'T WORKED OUT IN A LONG TIME? CAN I STILL DO THE WORKOUT?</p></div><div class="Accordion__IconContainer-ue81ns-2 fWwQcE"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="Icon-s8tlf2e-0 jkSJcy" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path fill="#5955dc" d="M15.02 6.8c.168 0 .3.048.396.144.096.096.144.228.144.396v1.908c0 .168-.048.3-.144.396-.096.096-.228.144-.396.144H9.584c-.12 0-.18.06-.18.18v5.328c0 .168-.048.3-.144.396-.096.096-.228.144-.396.144H6.956c-.168 0-.3-.048-.396-.144-.096-.096-.144-.228-.144-.396V9.968c0-.12-.06-.18-.18-.18H.8c-.168 0-.3-.048-.396-.144C.308 9.548.26 9.416.26 9.248V7.34c0-.168.048-.3.144-.396C.5 6.848.632 6.8.8 6.8h5.436c.12 0 .18-.06.18-.18V1.076c0-.168.048-.3.144-.396.096-.096.228-.144.396-.144h1.908c.168 0 .3.048.396.144.096.096.144.228.144.396V6.62c0 .12.06.18.18.18h5.436z"></path></svg></div></div>
```

So basically I need to properly deal with `icon="[object Object]" title="[object Object]" content="[object Object]">` to render as proper strings and not Objects

Comment: Could you provide `questions` structure?

Comment: console that tooltip ([object Object]) and provide exact value of that

Comment: console logs the proper string only evaluation on the DOM returns `object Object`

Comment: Which prop is that tooltip and link the accordion module you used

Comment: The tooltip is not a prop its just the normal html title for each element that has a title property

Comment: @OrkhanJafarov Could you please remove the negative vote on the quote so that I get help on this?

Comment: then use plain text in Accordion title prop, < Accordion title={question.question.toUpperCase()} ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check the props `title` and `content` in component `Accordion`.

The title attribute specifies extra information about an element. The information is most often shown as a tooltip text when the mouse moves over the element. The title attribute can be used on any HTML element (it will validate on any HTML element. However, it is not necessarily useful).

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp